# Inserting regular space between characters in Cocoa text drawing

Tags: cocoa, nsfont

Which is the font style used in NSFont to create alignment/space between characters?

I tried doing with this code, but not able to align the characters.

```
NSFont *font=[NSFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT"  size:15.0 ];
[textview setFont: font];
```

Please specify the font style name which suits the above mentioned problem.

Comment: I'd think this only works with mono-spaced fonts, such as Courier. There are also some sans-serif mono-spaced fonts, if that's what you want.

Comment: ya thanks a lot for the suggestion. it helped me. But how to display just 16 characters in one line on textview?

Comment: There's no “font style name” for this.

Answer (score 1):

What about trying [fontspace](http://www.fontspace.com/category/space?p=5) and pick the font you want.

And if you are looking to adjust the space between characters in a `UILabel` you can use:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth;
```

**Edit**: Above code for ios.

Comment: The question is about Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch. (Notice that the questioner is using NSFont, not UIFont.)